# getContentResolver().query android where clause

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

My query is regarding the creation of the function parameters for getting data from the database.

I want the cursor to returns only specific rows instead of complete recordset.

```
c= getContentResolver().query(uri, null, "column1=? \"mysearch\" or column2=? "\mysearch"\", null, "date DESC");
```

I want to get the results where **column1 like "mysearch" or column2 like "mysearch"**.

In the above example i have tried with some hardcoded values.

Regards,

Nirav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it after some workaround.

The correct query will be

```
String searchQuery = "column1 like '%" + searchKey
                + "%' or column2 like '%" + searchKey + "%'";


        c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, searchQuery, null,
                "date DESC");
```

Thanks,

Nirav