# ContentResolver query on Documents not filtering with selection

Tags: android-contentresolver, android-cursor

I am trying to filter documents on display name. Here is the code:

```
val files = ArrayList<String>(0)
val uri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(rootUri, DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(rootUri))
val searchQuery = "${DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME} LIKE ?"
val cursor = cResolver.query(uri, arrayOf(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME), searchQuery, arrayOf("'%aaa%'"), null)
while (cursor?.moveToNext() == true){
    files.add(cursor.getString(0).toString())
}
```

Here I am getting the output as `[ap.apk, mytext.txt, aaa]`
Whereas the expected output is just `[aaa]`

I have looked into other questions.
Accourding to these questions:
[where clause in contentProvider's query in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771636/where-clause-in-contentproviders-query-in-android)
[getContentResolver().query android where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498958/getcontentresolver-query-android-where-clause)
I also tried

```
val searchQuery = "${DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME} like '%aaa%'"
val cursor = cResolver.query(uri, arrayOf(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME), searchQuery, null, null)
```

But here also I get the same result. It would be great if someone can point me where I am making the mistake.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you fix this issue? same problem here, I can put garbage as the query and it doesn't cause an error, so it's being ignored

Comment: @Neo no, no solution. I have to loop over the cursor (`cursor.moveToNext()`) and manually filter.

Comment: Any luck since you posted this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

[A very similar question has been already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56263620/contentresolver-query-on-documentcontract-lists-all-files-disregarding-selection), the [unsatisfying answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61214849/3371707) is that the selection clauses and sort orders are ignored for descendants of the uri (which represents a folder).